# springboot mockito JUnit 5 Command builder pattern service unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5

I'm writing the unit test to code that I wrote for a service class. Here is the short part of my class for the question(s) I have:

```
public interface Command { public void execute(); }
```

```
public class MyServiceClass {

  private void doBusinessLogicValidation() {...}
  private void doBusinessLogicValidation2() {...}

  public void myMethod() {
     doBusinessLogicValidation();
     doBusinessLogicValidation2();

     Command myCommand = callPrivateMethodToCreateMyCommand();

     myCommand.execute();
  }

  private Command callPrivateMethodToCreateMyCommand() {
     MyObject commandObject = MyObject.builder().add("something").additional("else").build();
     return commandObject;
  }
}
```

The above code is fine and works w/ no problem and uses Java access modifiers correctly: short and concise. For the unit test, I need to override the callPrivateMethodToCreateMyCommand, but it is (correctly) private. PowerMock does not support JUnit 5.

I can change the callPrivateMethodToCreateMyCommand() to public and easily use JUnit's when()...thenReturn() semantics. BUT that breaks encapsulation and the reason why one would use private. And do not want to use protected.

My unit of test is the MyServiceClass and NOT into the execute() method of myCommand. What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,Jim

Comment: Usually decomposition helps. One idea is to extract `callPrivateMethodToCreateMyCommand` logic into a separate service that you could test it separately and mock as a part of MyServiceClass.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That is true -- but then I'm writing code to satisfy unit testing which is something that I do not necessarily want to do. Also I'm passing in the "something" and "else" (which in the real code are not string objects) to that new service. Seems like that is the "long way" to just make the private method public. Just wondering if I'm not missing something in the Mockito API.

Comment: it's your decision but usually this is a good idea to design for testability. As for making method public - I would rather make it package-private and probably use `spy` instead of mock.

Comment: That is true. Thank you Alex.